# Get Paths in SVG by Index

Tags: css

I've got an SVG element in my HTML. In that SVG there are 6 paths in various locations. I want to get the nth path with a pure CSS selector, however I cannot figure this out.

I have tried nth-child and nth-of-type, however they don't work in this case, because nth-child(1) will return all paths that are the first child of its parent, which in my case means it returns 3 paths. I want it to basically get all 6 paths, regardless of position in the DOM, and then get the 1st of those 6.

Minified HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <svg>
        <defs>
            <mask>
                <path></path> <-- I want to get this specifically.
                <g>
                    <path></path>
                    <path></path>
                    <path></path>
                    <path></path>
                </g>
            </mask>
        </defs>
        <g>
            <path></path>
        </g>
    </svg>
</body>
```

CSS selector:

```
path:nth-child(1)
```

I can't restructure my markup to make the selector work, because this is imported from an SVG file in real-time. Also, I'm thinking you could do this with jQuery, but I'm looking specifically for a pure CSS solution.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks all.

Comment: i think from css you can refer to element inside svg only if it has id.

Comment: I've come up only with :has() pseudo-class: `path:has(+ g)` to target a desired path element